# Expected Argument Error for .doc() when called on Firestore Collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to create a new user document in my Cloud Firestore database whenever a new user logs in. Each doc should have a unique id and I want a "uid" property for each user to match the unique auto-generated id for the doc. At first, I just always ran an update on the user, but I figured it could be helpful to separate my create and update logic. As you can see I haven't worked out how to query if a user exists, but I figured I should test the createUser function before continuing.

Anyway, while I was testing my createUser function I ran into a compilation error.

> ERROR in src/app/services/auth.service.ts(64,22): error TS2554:
>   Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

UPDATE:
When I try to run the function from localhost after compilation I get this error in the console.

> Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be
>   of type string, but it was: undefined

Here is my proposed solution:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './../models/user.model';
import { PermissionsService } from './permissions.service';

import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {
    AngularFirestore,
    AngularFirestoreDocument,
    AngularFirestoreCollection,
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
    usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User> = null;
    user: Observable<User>;

    constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private db: AngularFirestore,
        private permissionsService: PermissionsService,
    ) {
        this.usersCollection = db.collection('users');
        this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
            switchMap((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    return this.db
                        .doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`)
                        .valueChanges();
                } else {
                    return of(null);
                }
            }),
        );
    }

    loginGoogle() {
        const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
    }

    loginFacebook() {
        const provider = new auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
    }

    loginTwitter() {
        const provider = new auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
        return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
    }

    oAuthLogin(provider) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((credential) => {
            //if(the user exists already)
            //this.updateUserData(credential.user);
            //else
            this.createUser();
        });
    }

    createUser() {
        const newUserRef = this.usersCollection.doc<User>(); // Error here
        let newUser: User;
        this.user.subscribe((userData) => {
            newUser = {
                uid: newUserRef.id,
                email: userData.email,
                photoURL: userData.photoURL,
                displayName: userData.displayName,
                roles: {
                    member: true,
                },
                permissions: this.permissionsService.memberPermissions;
            };
        });

        newUserRef
            .set(newUser)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('created user');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Error adding user: ' + err);
            });
    }

    updateUserData(user) {
        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.db.doc(
            `users/${user.uid}`,
        );

        const userPermissions = this.addPermissions(userRef);
        console.log(userPermissions); // This works
        const data: User = {
            uid: user.uid,
            email: user.email,
            photoURL: user.photoURL,
            displayName: user.displayName,
            roles: {
                member: true,
            }, // I need to make sure this keeps current user roles
            permissions: userPermissions,
        };
        console.log(data); // This works

        userRef
            .set(data)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Success: Data for userDoc overwritten');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('Error writing to userDoc: ' + err);
            });
    }

    addPermissions(userRef) {
        const tempPermissions = [];
        userRef.valueChanges().subscribe((userdata) => {
            if (userdata.roles.reader === true) {
                tempPermissions.push(this.permissionsService.memberPermissions);
            }
            if (userdata.roles.author === true) {
                tempPermissions.push(this.permissionsService.authorPermissions);
            }
            if (userdata.roles.admin === true) {
                tempPermissions.push(this.permissionsService.adminPermissions);
            }
        });
        return tempPermissions;
    }

    checkPermissions(permission: string) {
        if (!this.user) {
            return false;
        } else {
            this.user.subscribe((data) => {
                for (const p of data.permissions) {
                    if (p === permission) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    }

    logout() {
        this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
        this.user = null;
    }
}
```

I checked the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) on the .doc() function and it should work fine with 0 arguments. It should be returning an empty doc reference. However, it keeps throwing the error saying it expects 1 argument. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: As far as I can see here, `usersCollection` is a `AngularFirestoreCollection`, not a CollectionReference.

Comment: You're right. Is there anyway to use the .doc()  (or any other) function to generate a new empty document with an AngularFirestoreCollection?

Comment: Sorry, I've never actually used Angular, and the documentation that I saw wasn't clear on this.  Maybe raise the issue on their GitHub?

Comment: Good idea. I'll post a question on there.